# Maven archetype for a JBoss esb project

Tags: maven, jboss-esb

I tried searching if a Maven archetype existed for creating a basic JBoss ESB project and couldn't find one. the closest I got was this link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBESB-2098
but looks like there wasn't much progress on that. Does anyone know if an archetype for JBoss esb project creation exist? if not, I may have to come up with one for my team. Appreciate your answers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did, so its useful for someone else who is trying the same:

Create a JBoss ESB template project with files and folders in the desired format.

Open Cmd prompt and goto the root of this project and enter:
 mvn archetype:create-from-project

Once the Build is successful, the archetype resources gets created under the target folder of this project.

Now move the archetype resources, archetype-metdata and project files along with the generated POM file to a new project which will basically act as your new template archetype project.

Do a mvn install and now you are ready to use your custom Maven JBossESB archetype!

If you want to extend this and have this as an Eclipse plugin, this link describes how to do it. pretty useful feature IMO
http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-custom-maven